# SQL Project Deploy to SQL Server on VM through Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure, continuous-integration

I am trying to setup SQL Server DACPAC project deploying to SQL Server on a VM through Visual Studio Team Services Continuous Integration scripts.
Here is my build definition
[image]

[image]
For server name I entered public IP of the VM, for Admin Login I entered Admin Account user name on that VM,

Then I got the following error in build

> [error]Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Deployment
>   on one or more machines failed.
>   System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException:
>   Connecting to remote server xx.xxx.xx.xx failed with the following
>   error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the
>   specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over
>   the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is
>   enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM
>   firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote
>   computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

Then I tried the following powershell commands on SQL VM

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
winrm quickconfig -transport:http
```

Second command hang up with the following message

> Configure LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy to grant administrative rights
>   remotely to local users.

Then I tried the following
[image]

Inbound ports
[image]

netstat -ant|findstr 5985
[image]

Comment: @Walter-MSFT no

Comment: Hi, do you open port 5985 on Windows Firewall?

Comment: probably I need to add listener for 5986. please check my updated question with screen shots. When I selected WinRm from Inboud rules option, it auto populated 5986 as port so I added it as is, then when I read at different places it is by default 5985 so I added custom inbound port for 5985

Comment: If you want winrm listening on 5986, you need configure https certificate.

Comment: This [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/02/11/configuring-winrm-over-https-to-enable-powershell-remoting/) will help you configure winrm listen on 5986, you could check it. I test it many times, it works for me.

Comment: isn't 5986 already listening as per the command prompt screen shot I posted over here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157449/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-habo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should ensure winrm service is listening.

```
netstat -ant|findstr 5985
```

By default, the port is listening on 5985. If the service is not listening, please execute

```
winrm quickconfig
```

Secondly, you should open port on VM Windows Firewall and Azure NSG(Inbound rules).

[image]

For test, you should ensure you could winrm your SQL VM on your local PC.

Comment: Extremely helpful. Thank you very much :)